# How to dynamically populate a filter list with "first match" on a row, using excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

[image: I have no good description]

The image is an example of what I am working with. I am trying to write a formula in my leftmost column, just under the listbox cell that you can see, which will find a string/value match in that row. I have called it "x" in the screenshot.

I will of course copy this formula to other rows below as well. I intend to use this "first match" to populate the filter list (listbox cell) that you can see in the leftmost column.

So far, I have tried variants of Hlookup and Vlookup, but was not successful. How can I get this to work?

EDIT 1: The value "x" itself is the return value. (*Incorrect! Please See EDIT 3*)

EDIT 2: Formulae used -- Will do so later. Said excel file is on another machine that I cannot access right now.

**EDIT 3**: Sorry. I would actually like the return value to be the corresponding date. For e.g., in the first row, the return value after finding the "match" would be 19. And so on. Having the date rather than x makes more sense to me now, because on some columns, the "x" might be as far as in September, and on some others it can be in June. I will format the numbers to be "dd-mon" for clarity on future revisions of my sheet.

Comment: What should it return when it finds a match?

Comment: Can you please add the formula you are trying?

Answer (score 0):

Use

> =Match("x",1D array)

to return the first match in the sorted array.

Added:

> = Offset(Date Row,0,Match("x",1D array)-1)

Comment: I'm sorry. I realised I had made a mistake after reading your reply. I made another edit to the question, EDIT 3. Please take a look at it, and modify your answer correspondingly.

Comment: @Surio I made a mistake too, which is now corrected.

Answer (score 0):

`HLOOKUP` looks for matches and returns what's on, or below the match if found.

You could use `INDEX` and `MATCH` as a workaround which is just as quick (if not slightly faster).

```
=INDEX($T3:$AP3, MATCH("x", T4:AP4, 0))
```

Change the range accordingly.

If your string could be anything but a blank cell, you could use:

```
=INDEX($T3:$AP3, MATCH(true, INDEX((T4:AP4<>""),0), 0))
```

Answer (score -1):

=IF(AVERAGE(lookup(2,1/C44:C46<>"")=1,2,SUM(LOOKUP(2,1/D44:D46<>""),0)))
IF(AVERAGE(lookup(2,1/C44:C46<>"")=1,SUM(LOOKUP(2,1/D44:D46<>""),0)))

last row entry match **example 1 or 2**  so please correct formula

Comment: Without explanation this answer is not very valuable. Why would you use AVERAGE and SUM over LOOKUPS?